# Is It possible to dynamically remove indexing on a field on Elasticsearch using spring data?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to index all the fields of an Elasticsearch index when building the index, but after some time, if needed change the `index` value to false and improve the performance by removing indexing from some of the fields.

As I searched, read the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) and tested it with spring data when I set `index = false` after building the index in `@Field` there is no change and the field is still searchable.

```kotlin
@Document(indexName = "book")
@Setting(refreshInterval = "30s", shards = 3)
class Book(
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    var id: String? = null,
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword )
    var title: String? = null,
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword,index = false)
    val isbn: String)
```

I wanted to know if there is another solution to change the indexing of fields dynamically after building the index using spring data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run the modified program with a new index name to create a new index with the adjusted mapping and then manually do a reindexing from the old to the new index: [Elasticsearch documentation about reindexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/docs-reindex.html).